# R subsetting vectors using an expression to form indices

Tags: r

I came across something which surprized me about subsetting in R.  I have a vector of ascending values, and want to use only those values close to the middle.  So, I just needed something like this:

```
x <- 1:10
m <- 5
x[(m-1):(m+1)]
```

which returns the middle 3 values (that is what I wanted).  But by mistake I used:

```
x[m-1:m+1]
```

To my surprize, the vector 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 was returned. Could someone please help me understand how R is interpretting this?

Comment: `?Syntax` Read about Operator Syntax and Precedence.

Answer (score 2):

This is just about operator precedence. *x[m-1:m+1]* is interpreted as *x[m-(1:m)+1]* (and not as *x[(m-1):(m+1)]*) or *x[m+1 - (1:m)]*, which in your case is *x[c(5,4,3,2,1)]*, since *6 - (1:5) = rep(6,5) - (1:5)*.

Comment: Thank you sandipan!

Comment: you are most welcome kb'